# Format Numbers in Textfields using Swift

Tags: xcode, uitextfield, swift, ios8

I am trying to format a number from a `UITextfield`, as its being typed, to a decimal with commas.

I have done so with the following code:

```
@IBAction func editingDidBegin(sender : AnyObject)
{
    costField.addTarget(self, action: Selector("textFieldDidChange:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
}

func textFieldDidChange(theTextField:UITextField) -> Void
{
    var textFieldText = theTextField.text.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(",", withString: " ", options: NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch, range: Range(start: theTextField.text.startIndex, end: theTextField.text.endIndex))
    var formatter:NSNumberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle
    var formattedOutput = formatter.stringFromNumber(textFieldText.bridgeToObjectiveC().integerValue)

    costField.text = formattedOutput
}
```

The problem with this, is after four digits are entered, everything after the comma is deleted. For example if I enter 4000 it formats to 4,000, then if I type another number like 8 it reformats to 48.

Is there another way I can format this, maybe through IB or how can I fix the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the line with:

```
var textFieldText = theTextField.text.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(",", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch, range: Range(start: theTextField.text.startIndex, end: theTextField.text.endIndex))
```

(I only removed the space between the double quotes).

Fact is, NSNumberFormatter doesn't like the added spaces in the string.

Works fine afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late to the party but this worked well for me.

```
var phoneNumber = " 1 (888) 555-5551    "

var strippedPhoneNumber = "".join(phoneNumber.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet))
```

It takes out the spaces and strips out the non decimal numeric characters.

The end result is "1888555551"

Answer (score 0):

I've updated this answer to the newest version of swift.  This borrows 90% from the two answers above however, also accounts for nil exception from the textfield when the textfield is cleared.

```
func textFieldDidChangeCommas(theTextField:UITextField) -> Void
{
    if theTextField.text != nil {

        var textFieldText = theTextField.text!.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(",", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch, range: Range(start: theTextField.text!.startIndex, end: theTextField.text!.endIndex))
        var formatter:NSNumberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle
        if textFieldText != "" {
            var formattedOutput = formatter.stringFromNumber(Int(textFieldText)!)
            costField.text = formattedOutput
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it would be a complete solution if you had added how to call the method to simplify work for those looking for a quick solution without having to look else where, especially beginners.

Comment: it would be a complete solution if you had added how to call the method to simplify work for those looking for a quick solution without having to look else where, especially beginners. but, both of these worked:   `textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PostPaymentViewController. textFieldDidChangeCommas(_:))    , for: .editingChanged)`    AND    
        `textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController. textFieldDidChangeCommas)    , for: .editingChanged)` .           Can someone explain briefly please.